# prediction() working wrong with (apparently) correct model

Tags: r, r-caret, predict

I'm writing a script in R but, predict() function is returning me a wrong prediction (NO) based in data clearly YES. I don't know what is wrong so, if you could help, i would be very grateful.
This is the code:

```
library(RWeka)
library(caret)
library(datasets)

table_golf = read.table("C:/Users/Mario S-Herrero/Desktop/golf.txt.txt",
                        header = T,
                        sep = ",",
)
data_golf <- as.data.frame(table_golf)

data_golf$Panorama=as.factor(data_golf$Panorama)
data_golf$Temperatura=as.factor(data_golf$Temperatura)
data_golf$Humedad=as.factor(data_golf$Humedad)
data_golf$Viento=as.factor(data_golf$Viento)
data_golf$Jugar=as.factor(data_golf$Jugar)

modelC45 <- J48(`Jugar` ~ ., data = data_golf)
modelC45
plot(modelC45)

#Crear matriz, convertir a data y ya pedir la predicción.

nuevopartido = read.table("C:/Users/Mario S-Herrero/Desktop/input.txt",
                        header = T,
                        sep = ",",
)
input <- as.data.frame(nuevopartido)
input$Panorama=as.factor(input$Panorama)
input$Temperatura=as.factor(input$Temperatura)
input$Humedad=as.factor(input$Humedad)
input$Viento=as.factor(input$Viento)

prediccion <- predict(modelC45,input)
plot(prediccion)
```

golf.txt

```
Panorama,Temperatura,Humedad,Viento,Jugar
Soleado,Calor,Alta,Ligero,No
Soleado,Calor,Alta,Fuerte,No
Nublado,Calor,Alta,Ligero,Si
Lluvia,Medio,Alta,Ligero,Si
Lluvia,Frio,Normal,Ligero,Si
Lluvia,Frio,Normal,Fuerte,No
Nublado,Frio,Normal,Fuerte,Si
Soleado,Medio,Alta,Ligero,No
Soleado,Medio,Normal,Ligero,Si
Lluvia,Medio,Normal,Ligero,Si
Soleado,Medio,Normal,Fuerte,Si
Nublado,Medio,Alta,Fuerte,Si
Nublado,Calor,Normal,Ligero,Si
Lluvia,Medio,Alta,Fuerte,No
```

input.txt

```
Panorama,Temperatura,Humedad,Viento
Nublado,Medio,Normal,Normal
```

Keep attention to "nublado" case is always "Si" but plotting says "No", whats wrong?

Thanks for your time!

Expecting "Si" result instead "No"

Comment: None of your training data has `Viento == "Normal"`, so perhaps that breaks the model???

Comment: I agree with @AndrewGustar.  Also, why do you think the answer should be "Si"?  There are 4 Nublado, of them 1 Medio, 2 Normal, 0 Si.  I'm not sure you should know what to expect with that.